# Matplotlib: Hide/remove a subplot from a series of plots but keep the order of the rest

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to better describe my question I have compiled the following example (ok it's not the most elaborated one but it works):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 10)

i = 1
for dset in ['set1','set2','set3']:
    axes[0,0].plot(x, y*i, label=dset)
    axes[0,0].legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})

    axes[0,1].plot(x, y*2*i, label=dset)
    axes[0,1].legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})

    axes[1,0].plot(x, y*3*i, label=dset)
    axes[1,0].legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})

    axes[1,1].plot(x, y*4*i, label=dset)
    axes[1,1].legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})

    i+=1
plt.show()
```

So the output should be the following plot:

[image]

And the question is how can I hide/remove let's say the dataset 1 (blue line) from the first subplot only, but keeping all blue lines (the rest of the first datasets) in the next subplots?

Comment: "ok it's not the most elaborated one but it works" -> not over elaborated but it works is the best kind of example. Wish more beginners asked questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fast solution, just query if the current loop variable is "set1" and if so, don't plot it. By using a list of colors we can make sure that the sets keep their color throughout the 4 subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 10)

colors=["b", "limegreen", "crimson"]
sets= ['set1','set2','set3']
for i,dset,c in zip(range(len(sets)+1)[1:], sets, colors):
    if dset != "set1":
        axes[0,0].plot(x, y*i, color=c, label=dset)
    axes[0,1].plot(x, y*2*i, color=c,label=dset)
    axes[1,0].plot(x, y*3*i, color=c,label=dset)
    axes[1,1].plot(x, y*4*i, color=c,label=dset)

# only add legends once at the end    
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Another solution can be to remove the line after it has been drawn. However you'd need to know which line to remove (here we take the first one).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 10)

#colors=["b", "limegreen", "crimson"]
sets= ['set1','set2','set3']
for i,dset in zip(range(len(sets)+1)[1:], sets):

    axes[0,0].plot(x, y*i, label=dset)
    axes[0,1].plot(x, y*2*i,label=dset)
    axes[1,0].plot(x, y*3*i, label=dset)
    axes[1,1].plot(x, y*4*i, label=dset)

axes[0,0].lines[0].remove()
# only add legends once at the end    
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.legend(loc=0, frameon=False, prop={'size':10})
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this solution but is there any way to say that directly to subplots without inserting manually the colors ? (without editing the rest of the script.)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by "say that directly to subplots".

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't express it accurately. I mean if there is any other way to (or attribute) on the subplots that just skips the current plot. (I hope it is more clear now).

Comment: I'm still lost about what you want, but I added another possible solution without changing colors.

Comment: Sorry for my really delayed reply, and the confusion. Your last solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!